# Is there a term for two words together that would be an oxymoron, but aren't due to context or usage?

Tags: meaning, oxymoron

Like 'pretty ugly'. The most used meaning of 'pretty' is contradictory to 'ugly', and it could feasibly be used to mean something like (if it were an oxymoron), 'someone who may be considered ugly, but is actually kinda pretty'. But of course it actually means, considerably ugly. Is there a term to describe such pairings?

Edit: I'll add more examples as I think of them:

Don't trust casinos, they're fairly rigged.

I'm an f'ing celibate.

The doctor gave me a sick healthy report.

I'm a bad good kid. -- Like they are morally good, but are bad (not morally bad) at actually making much out of it, as some role-models may do. Like they are comparing themselves to others. As opposed to a kid who is generally a good kid, but does still get into trouble some, so they may be teetering on the edge of not being considered a good kid. Which would actually be an oxymoron.

Comment: It's related, but they ask if it's considered an oxymoron. I'm figuring it's not, and wondering what the term is for the cases when it isn't, but may seem like it. So the question of what the term is called is such cases isn't answered, if there is such a term.

Comment: In other words, I'm asking the follow up question, as in, is there a term for it.

Comment: They examples they give are somewhat borderline, since the origin of the term shrimp does come from it being small. And truly false is fairly close to an oxymoron, since 'certainly' is like being true.

Comment: It might not be common enough to have its own term.

Comment: puns?..........

Comment: Maybe in some cases, but I don't think saying 'pretty ugly' is a pun.

Comment: You could be right though, I'm not sure if some could consider these all puns. Though I feel like puns require intent, like they are said to be puns on purpose. But yeah, not sure.

Comment: Let's call them sophomorisms.

Comment: This is literally the definition of an oxymoron, particularly in older texts: a phrase which appears self-contradictory but makes sense figuratively. Look it up in an encyclopedia.